# What does "second citizenship platforms" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I already googled *second citizenship platforms* but I couldn't find any explanation.

> The group's annual report is based on wealth statistics, property data, investor visa information and interviews with migration experts, **second citizenship platforms,** wealth managers and property agents.

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2017/02/21/pf/millionaires-moving-migration-australia-france/index.html?iid=SF_LN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, a *second citizenship platform* is a platform for second citizenship.

You can infer from context that *platform* here refers to a kind of company or professional, as it is in parallel with *experts*, *managers*, and *agents*. This is an unusual use of *[platform](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/platform#platform__14)*, but consistent with that word's sense of a system or program that provides services. As Macmillan puts it,

> 6. something that allows something else to happen
>
>    > platform for: The funding would provide a platform for growth and development.

The source mentioned in the article, the *[The 2017 Global Wealth Review (GWR): Worldwide Wealth and Wealth Migration Trends](http://www.researchandmarkets.com/reports/4070961/the-2017-global-wealth-review-gwr-worldwide)*, is paywalled; however, an [earlier edition of the report](http://nebula.wsimg.com/33c082a103704a172bf3bd8d8288db65?AccessKeyId=70E2D0A589B97BD675FB&disposition=0&alloworigin=1) is freely available, and confirms that the *platform* in question is a type of firm.

> According to Nadia Read, head of world residence and citizenship platform LIO Global: “the main reason people apply for a second residence or citizenship is to ensure freedom of global mobility and access, as well as security and wealth protection for their families.“

A *second citizenship* (or a *second passport*, by metonymy) is commonly an *[economic citizenship](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-27674135)*, one acquired through investment in a country's economy, and undertaken to take advantage of that country's laws or tax regime as compared to one's homeland. It is a type of *dual citizenship*, a broader term encompassing the holding of citizenship in multiple countries, including where the hold is on the heart as well as the wallet.

So, *second citizenship platform* refers to firms like [LIO Global](http://lio-global.com/), [Arton Capital](http://www.artoncapital.com/) or [Henley & Partners](https://www.henleyglobal.com/) which advise the wealthy on matters of citizenship and residence, and provide programs through which they can acquire second citizenships.